# How to get key set from JSON in ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, json, oracle12c

I have JSON object in one column:

```
{
  "key1": {json_object1},
  "key2": {json_object2}
}
```

How to get key set for it ?

Comment: 12.2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702150/oracle-json-to-key-value-pair-table

Comment: Oracle 12.1 unfortunately :/